# Add dimensions to a tensor and duplicate values along the new axes

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have a 2D ndarray X with

```
X.shape == (m, n)
```

I'd like to add two more dimensions to X, while copying the values along these new axes. i.e. I want

```
new_X.shape == (m, n, k, l)
```

and for all i,j

```
new_X[i, j, :, :] = X[i, j]
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get a tensor view with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) -

```
np.broadcast_to(a[...,None,None],a.shape+(k,l)) # a is input array
```

The benefit would be that there's no extra memory overhead with it and hence virtually free rumtime.

If you need an array output with its own memory space, append with `.copy()`.

Sample run -

```
In [9]: a =  np.random.rand(2,3)

In [10]: k,l = 4,5

In [11]: np.broadcast_to(a[...,None,None],a.shape+(k,l)).shape
Out[11]: (2, 3, 4, 5)

# Verify memory space sharing
In [12]: np.shares_memory(a,np.broadcast_to(a[...,None,None],a.shape+(k,l)))
Out[12]: True

# Verify virtually free runtime
In [17]: a =  np.random.rand(100,100)
    ...: k,l = 100,100
    ...: %timeit np.broadcast_to(a[...,None,None],a.shape+(k,l))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.41 µs per loop
```

Comment: Precisely what I needed, thank you for the elaborated answer